# Why do all of these methods of accessing an array work?

Tags: perl, hash, arrays

It seems to me that some of these should fail, but they all output what they are supposed to:

```
$, = "\n";
%test = (
    "one" => ["one_0", "one_1"],
    "two" => ["two_0", "two_1"]
);

print @{$test{"one"}}[0],
      @{$test{"one"}}->[0],
      $test{"two"}->[0],
      $test{"one"}[1];
```

Why is this?

Comment: Because, in Perl, There's More Than One Way To Do It.  That's part of the language philosophy.  It isn't univerally shared.

Comment: Would you prefer if one or more of them *didn't* output what it's supposed to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first example is different than the others. It is an [array slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) -- but in disguise since you are only asking for one item.

```
@{$test{"one"}}[0];

@{$test{"one"}}[1, 0];  # Another slice example.
```

Your other examples are alternative ways of de-referencing items within a multi-level data structure. However, the use of an array for de-referencing is deprecated (see [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html)).

```
@{$test{"one"}}->[0]; # Deprecated. Turn on 'use warnings'.
$test{"two"}->[0];    # Valid.
$test{"one"}[1];      # Valid but easier to type.
```

Regarding the last example, two subscripts sitting next to each other have an implied `->` between them. See, for example, the discussion of the [Arrow Rule](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Arrow-Rule) in perlreftut.

Comment: It's worth noting that an array slice in scalar context returns the last element in the slice, much like the comma operator `,`.